Find the minimum non-missing date among dates in a row in R?
I have the following data frame in R:
USUBJID <- c(1, 2, 3)
EOT <- c("2021-08-17", "2020-08-10", "2020-08-10")
DTHDT <- c(NA, "2021-04-10", "2022-08-05")
EOSDT <- c("2023-08-17", "2021-04-10", "2022-08-05")

# Create DataFrame
dat<-data.frame(USUBJID=USUBJID, EOTDT=as.Date(c("2021-08-17", "2020-08-10", "2020-08-10")), 
                DTHDT=as.Date(c(NA, "2021-04-10", "2022-08-05`enter code here`")), 
                EOSDT=as.Date(c("2023-08-17", "2021-04-10", "2022-08-05"))) 

I would like to generate a fifth column that takes the minimum non-missing date among the 3 other dates for each USUBJID. For instance, the the first subject that would be 2021-08-17.

Are the values of USUBJID ever repeated? If not then it seems all you need is the row-wise min date.

Base R:
cbind(dat, minimum = apply(dat[-1], 1, min, na.rm = TRUE))

  USUBJID      EOTDT      DTHDT      EOSDT    minimum
1       1 2021-08-17       <NA> 2023-08-17 2021-08-17
2       2 2020-08-10 2021-04-10 2021-04-10 2020-08-10
3       3 2020-08-10 2022-08-05 2022-08-05 2020-08-10 

cbind(dat, minimum = do.call(pmin, c(dat[-1], na.rm = TRUE)))
  USUBJID      EOTDT      DTHDT      EOSDT    minimum
1       1 2021-08-17       <NA> 2023-08-17 2021-08-17
2       2 2020-08-10 2021-04-10 2021-04-10 2020-08-10
3       3 2020-08-10 2022-08-05 2022-08-05 2020-08-10


dat %>%
  mutate(minimum = exec(pmin, !!!dat[-1], na.rm = TRUE))

  USUBJID      EOTDT      DTHDT      EOSDT    minimum
1       1 2021-08-17       <NA> 2023-08-17 2021-08-17
2       2 2020-08-10 2021-04-10 2021-04-10 2020-08-10
3       3 2020-08-10 2022-08-05 2022-08-05 2020-08-10


dat %>%
   mutate(minimum = min(c_across(everything()), na.rm = TRUE), .by = USUBJID)
  USUBJID      EOTDT      DTHDT      EOSDT    minimum
1       1 2021-08-17       <NA> 2023-08-17 2021-08-17
2       2 2020-08-10 2021-04-10 2021-04-10 2020-08-10
3       3 2020-08-10 2022-08-05 2022-08-05 2020-08-10

dat %>%
   pivot_longer(-USUBJID, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
   summarise(minimum = min(value), .by = USUBJID) %>%
   right_join(dat)

# A tibble: 3 × 5
  USUBJID minimum    EOTDT      DTHDT      EOSDT     
    <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    
1       1 2021-08-17 2021-08-17 NA         2023-08-17
2       2 2020-08-10 2020-08-10 2021-04-10 2021-04-10
3       3 2020-08-10 2020-08-10 2022-08-05 2022-08-05


I just want to add that I have additional columns in the dataset, I would not want to go across all columns, but only among the 3 specific date columns (EOT, DTHDT, EOSDT). Thank you for the multiple options, though!

I tried this but it results  in minimum being a number and not a date. Can you please let me know how to change the code, so that it returns a date and not a number?
  mutate(minimum = min(EOT,DTHDT,EOSDT, na.rm = TRUE), .by = USUBJID)```

@MKro that is coercing the dates into numbers. Consider wrapping the results with as.Date function eg dat%>%  mutate(minimum = as.Date(min(EOT,DTHDT,EOSDT, na.rm = TRUE)), .by = USUBJID) or use pmin instead of min eg dat%>%   mutate(minimum = pmin(EOT,DTHDT,EOSDT, na.rm = TRUE))

This solution will work if you have other non-date columns besides USUBJID. Additionally, if you only need row-wise min dates then you can remove the .by argument:
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

dat |>
  mutate(x = pmap_vec(pick(where(is.Date)), \(...) min(..., na.rm = T)), .by = USUBJID)

You can create a function with the default to remove NA to shorten the code a bit:
earliest <- partial(min, na.rm = T)

dat |>
  mutate(x = pmap_vec(pick(where(is.Date)), earliest), .by = USUBJID)

