How to obtain all the numeric variables in data frame and use in another function in R
the below example is to obtain the min value among 3 columns, we can use the pmin(V1, V2, V3).
if we have lots of columns, how to get the minimal value among all numeric variables especially using the tidyverse
df <- data.frame(V1= runif(3, 1, 10), V2 =runif(3, 1, 10), V3 = runif(3, 1, 10))
df |> dplyr::mutate(min = pmin(V1, V2, V3))
#>         V1       V2       V3      min
#> 1 9.416508 7.433805 8.318565 7.433805
#> 2 9.194577 5.935652 4.486447 4.486447
#> 3 2.537344 9.764215 1.473823 1.473823

Created on 2024-06-28 with reprex v2.1.0
Automatically get all numeric columns and passed to a functione, e.g. pmin.
I try the following function dplyr::pick and dplyr::where but fail to get right results
df <- data.frame(V1= runif(3, 1, 10), V2 =runif(3, 1, 10), V3 = runif(3, 1, 10))
df |> dplyr::mutate(x= pmin(dplyr::pick(dplyr::where(is.numeric))))


use df as it is. ie do.call(pmin, df)

check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78679487/find-the-minimum-non-missing-date-among-dates-in-a-row-in-r/78679518#78679518 for solutions

Try c_across:
df |> rowwise() |> mutate(min=min(c_across(where(is.numeric))))

     V1    V2    V3 V4      min
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1  3.59  8.95  5.75 A      3.59
2  8.09  9.46  9.03 B      8.09
3  4.68  1.41  5.96 C      1.41


For more efficiency, the Rfast package is worth a try.
library(Rfast)
rownth(as.matrix(df[,sapply(df, is.numeric)]), elems = rep(1, 3))
#[1] 3.588198 8.094746 1.410008


> set.seed(123)
> df <- data.frame(V1=runif(3, 1, 10), V2=runif(3, 1, 10), 
                   V3=runif(3, 1, 10), V4=LETTERS[1:3])
> df
        V1       V2       V3 V4
1 3.588198 8.947157 5.752949  A
2 8.094746 9.464206 9.031771  B
3 4.680792 1.410008 5.962915  C


Thank you for your ansewer. rowwise() is very concise but not efficient, please check the benchmark below

Yes - it's super slow. I have added another option for you to consider.

You could use pmin with exec/do.call:
df %>%
   mutate(min = exec(pmin, !!!select(., where(is.numeric))))

        V1       V2       V3      min
1 9.416508 7.433805 8.318565 7.433805
2 9.194577 5.935652 4.486447 4.486447
3 2.537344 9.764215 1.473823 1.473823


Note that in base R you could do:
cbind(df, min = do.call(pmin, Filter(is.numeric, df)))

        V1       V2       V3      min
1 9.416508 7.433805 8.318565 7.433805
2 9.194577 5.935652 4.486447 4.486447
3 2.537344 9.764215 1.473823 1.473823


Thanks. if using rlang, I tyr to use this code df |> dplyr::mutate(min = pmin(!!!rlang::syms(names(purrr::keep(df,is.numeric)))))

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(V1=runif(3, 1, 10), V2=runif(3, 1, 10), 
                 V3=runif(3, 1, 10), V4=LETTERS[1:3])
df
#>         V1       V2       V3 V4
#> 1 3.588198 8.947157 5.752949  A
#> 2 8.094746 9.464206 9.031771  B
#> 3 4.680792 1.410008 5.962915  C


bench::mark(
  df |> rowwise() |> mutate(min = min(c_across(where(is.numeric)))) |> ungroup(),
  df |> mutate(min = do.call(pmin, keep(df, is.numeric))) |> as_tibble(),
  df |> mutate(min = exec(pmin, !!!keep(df, is.numeric))) |> as_tibble(),
  df |> dplyr::mutate(min = pmin(!!!rlang::syms(names(purrr::keep(df,is.numeric))))) |> as_tibble()
)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#>   expression                           min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>                      <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 ungroup(mutate(rowwise(df), mi…   2.98ms   3.54ms      255.    2.82MB     12.9
#> 2 as_tibble(mutate(df, min = do.…    738µs 923.95µs      959.  975.67KB     12.7
#> 3 as_tibble(mutate(df, min = exe…  749.2µs    973µs      913.   17.75KB     12.5
#> 4 as_tibble(dplyr::mutate(df, mi…  741.5µs  933.3µs      855.    1.61KB     12.6

Created on 2024-06-28 with reprex v2.1.0

We can use max.col as well
d <- Filter(is.numeric,df)
df$min <- d[cbind(1:nrow(d), max.col(-d))]

which would give
> df
        V1       V2       V3      min
1 9.070275 6.155680 9.085507 6.155680
2 3.389578 9.173870 9.502077 3.389578
3 4.349115 2.815137 6.947180 2.815137

Data
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(V1 = runif(3, 1, 10), V2 = runif(3, 1, 10), V3 = runif(3, 1, 10))

